# Regex to capture ApiAuth Headers

Tags: regex, ruby

I have the following scenario sending Auth Headers to an application that can range from the following:

```
"APIAuth 5b6b7ed3b9708d1168455da4:hW1ZeYYLJFGBP8tEHAEGoiGD1xM="

"APIAuth-HMAC-SHA256 5b6b7ed3b9708d1168455da4:hW1ZeYYLJFGBP8tEHAEGoiGD1xM="
  

etc.
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to capture `APIAuth` and `APIAuth-HMAC-SHA256` from the header leaving me the `client_id:signature` like so:

```
string = '5b6b7ed3b9708d1168455da4:hW1ZeYYLJFGBP8tEHAEGoiGD1xM='
```

I want to be able to grab this value from any `APIAut-WHATEVER-ENCRYPTION`

I've been playing around with regex's but the best I have was this `/\ABearer\s+/i`. I thought this would have worked to grab both because the `\s+` is more than one of any single character so I don't know why its not working. Could someone please assist? Regexs are not my strong suit. Thank you.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for your quick reply. I hope my edit helps makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example strings, you could match the parts that you want:

```
\bAPIAuth(?:-\S+)?\s+\K[^\s:"]+:[^\s:"]+
```

**Explanation**

- `\bAPIAuth` A word boundary, followed by `APIAuth`
- `(?:-\S+)?` Optionally match `-` and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `\s+\K` Match 1+ whitespace chars and forget what is matched so far using `\K`
- `[^\s:"]+:[^\s:"]+` Match `:` surrounded by chars other than a whitespace char or `:` or `"` if those are also part of the string

See a [rubular regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/iRVun3TUDZ7myl).

You could also match only the first part, and then replace with an empty string.

```
\bAPIAuth(?:-\S+)?\s+
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xcyT7O/1)

Comment: Dan, if `str = "APIAuth 5b6b7ed3b9708d1168455da4:hW1ZeYYLJFGBP8tEHAEGoiGD1xM="`; that would be `str[/\bAPIAuth(?:-\S+)?\s+\K[^\s:"]+:[^\s:"]+/] #=> "5b6b7...1xM="` or `str.sub(/\bAPIAuth(?:-\S+)?\s+/, "") #=> "5b6b7...1xM="`.